# Changing size of new figure window on Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, layout, resize, figure

I am making a GUI to plot spectra using Matlab. I have included a button to save an image of the plot using this simple code:

```
fig=figure;

h=handles.axes2;

copyobj(h,fig);
```

But when the new figure opens up it only shows part of the plot
 [image]

I can resize the new figure manually but I'd rather the plot was automatically put in the centre when opened up. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Vera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
set(fig, 'Position', [100, 100, 1049, 895]);
```

where the values are defined as 
[left bottom width height]

Comment: thank you that worked great :) do you have any idea how to resize the plot in the new figure (it's quite small now)?